# What the purpose of 'bufp += nread;' in the Robust reading rio_read() function?

Tags: c, io, computer-science, robust

I'm reading the code below in Chapter 10 in the book called Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective. I understand all the code below except the line: bufp += nread; I found this line is pointless, because I don't see the point to increment the bufp pointer by nread?

Anyone can explain to me why bufp+= nread; exits there? Thank you very much!

```
ssize_t rio_readn(int fd, void *usrbuf, size_t n) 
{
    size_t nleft = n;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *bufp = usrbuf;

    while(nleft > 0) {
        if((nread = read(fd, bufp, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                nread = 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        else if (nread == 0)
            break;
        nleft -= nread;
        bufp += nread;
    }
    return (n - nleft);
}
```

I have tried the code without bufp += nread;, it worked without it. And I've searched online everywhere if anyone had the same concern as mine, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Could you comment on your understanding of what `nread = read(fd, bufp, nleft)` does? And also, do you have an understanding of what the purpose of `nleft` and the `while` loop is?

Comment: I think I figured out: 1) say in the middle of a read() to read 10 bytes from a file, after you read 3 bytes there is a signal interrupt to the read(), read() returned -1. 2)But you want to be able to continue the read() after the interruption, and there are already 3 bytes stored in the buffer bufp, which are usrbuf[0], usrbuf[1], usrbuf[2]. 3) So you read() again by setting nread = 0 but increment the pointer *bufp by nread/3 bytes, so *bufp points to buffer location &usrbuf[3], and when read() is called again the first 3 nread bytes that are already in the bufp buffer won't  be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

If `bufp` was *not* incremented, then the next `read()` would write over the previously read data. The way it works is that `read()` delivers `nread` bytes, which may be less than `nleft`. On the first call the read data occupies the buffer locations `usrbuf[0..nread-1]`. On the next call of `read()` after `bufp += nread;`, `bufp` will point to `usrbuf[nread]`, which is the next available byte in the buffer after what was previously read.

The only reason that code would work without the increment would be if the loop only ran once, or ran twice with the second `read()` reading zero bytes. Those two would in fact be the normal case for reading regular *files*, since then `read()` will get all of the available data. The reason that this function needs a loop, is that when reading from a pipe, `read()` will not wait for `nleft` bytes from the source, and instead return what is available at the time. (`read()` will wait for at least one byte or for EOF, so that if it returns zero, you know it got to EOF.) The loop assures that `n` bytes are read if they eventually become available from the pipe.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, it makes sense to me. I think the reason that my code worked is because I had write() followed the read() immediately, and which has not interrupt evolved.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the code without bufp += nread;, it worked without it. And I've searched online everywhere if anyone had the same concern as mine, but I didn't find it.

When you do a partial read (something you have not observed) and fill partially the buffer, and more data is to come, you will make a new `read()` to try to fill the rest of the buffer.  I'll try to explain first with comments the meaning of each statement in the `while` loop.

```
    while(nleft > 0) {  /* while there's still room in the buffer for more data */
        if((nread = read(fd, bufp, nleft)) < 0) {
            /* if nread  < 0, error checking must be done. */
            if (errno == EINTR)
                nread = 0; /* in case something interrupted the read, return
                            * 0, I have no clear idea if this is what is
                            * required, as some data can have been
                            * accumulated already, I should return n - nleft,
                            * as is done at the bottom, but can be fine,
                            * depending on the requirements.
                            */
            else
                return -1;  /* considered error, some data can be lost */
        }
        else if (nread == 0) /* nread == 0 is a special case (end of input) */
            break;
        /* now update the pointers to fill more space with another read if there's
         * still room in the buffer */
        nleft -= nread;  /* subtract the read from nleft to reflect the new
                          * available size in the buffer */
        bufp += nread;   /* advance the pointer nread positions, so next read
                          * doesn't overwrite the just read data */
    }
    return (n - nleft);  /* n - nleft is how much data has been read */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment, I think you comment said the same thing as  my reply to Brian61354270 above.